# arm motion planning

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed that there are two tutorial sets for arm navigation (arm_navigation and move_arm). Are the tutorials for arm_navigation still usable despite being for electric and diamondback?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99246/arm-motion-planning/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2013-11-09**:
The code really doesn't change from version to version, the only major update was the shift from rosbuild to catkin.  If you are using hydro and the tutorials require publishing transforms, you may have to look at the new tf2 they just released.  I'm not sure if its backwards compatible.

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-11-10**:
actually I Use groovy. I only ask this question Because the motion planing tutorials have got me quite confused on where to start for my custom robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're starting on developing new manipulation code *now*, I'd strongly suggest you use [MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/) on Hydro instead, because arm_navigation has been deprecated now. It's only working in Fuerte (and half-working in Groovy); from Hydro on, there won't be any more arm_navigation.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1